Uniqueness theorem for holomorphic functions on the boundary, Simple method?

Let $f$ be holomorphic in $G = \left\{  {z \in  \Bbb C : 0 < \arg z < \frac{\pi }{4}}\right\}$, and continuous on $\bar{G}$. If $f=0$ on $\left\lbrack  {a, b}\right\rbrack\subset (0,+\infty)$ , prove that $f$ is identically zero in $G$.

I have seen in Zeros of a holomorphic function on the boundary of a closed region that M/F Riesz theorem may applies. But I could not find a reference where the proof is located in.
Is there any elementrary proof for this simple domain? Just using Cauchy integral theorem/formula?
Consider $[f(z)]^8$, but discontinuity may occure on the positive real axis? Oh.
$u_x=v_x=0$ on $[a,b]$. But we do not know the contiuity of $u_x,v_x$, or else $v_y=u_y=0$ on $[a,b]$. This seeems unhelpful..

can't you just select a very small square in $\overline G$ with the bottom edge $\in [a,b]$ then translate its midpoint to the origin, so $g(z):= f(z+m)$ and then recover a standard introductory exercise?  i.e. consider $\prod_{k=1}^4 g\big(i^k\cdot z\big)$

Consider the rectangle $R$ with vertices at $a, a+i\epsilon, b+i\epsilon, b$ where $\epsilon$ is small enough st the interior of $R$ is included in $0<\arg z <\pi/4$ and use Schwarz reflection to extend $f$ holomorphically to the rectangle with vertices at $ a\pm i\epsilon,  b \pm i\epsilon$ (by the formula $\overline {f(\bar z)}$ as usual) and then $(a,b)$ is interior so $f$ is identically zero on $R$ hence on the original domain
